# Efficient way to concatenate hundreds of RxScala Observables (each with millions of events to emit)?

Tags: scala, reactive-programming, observable

I have data stored on disk, files of millions of records, one per day.  I have a relatively efficient deserializer which produces Observables that emit the records, quickly enough for now (1.5M records/s).

What I want is to now concatenate these Observables so that I can get an uninterrupted stream of a span of multiple days.  I was thrilled when something this simple worked:

```
val nilObs: Observable[Record] = Observable.empty
val allObs = dates.map(reader.recordsForDate(_)).foldLeft(nilObs)(_ ++ _)
```

However, the above results in an Observable with awful throughput - with 200 concatenated Observables, I was seeing 50-100k/s, vs the 1.5M/s that I was expecting.

I haven't profiled it yet, but looking at https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/blob/master/rxjava-core/src/main/java/rx/internal/operators/OperatorConcat.java it is doing a lot of work with queues - I wonder if I've created N queues, rather than N Observables on one queue?

Is there a more efficient way of concatenating Observables in this way?

Comment: Poking around further, having gotten the lead that the inner concatenation implementation has a full queue infrastructure, I wonder if I should be using concatMap or otherwise an Observable which emits Observables which I then concat... ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is definitely at least one faster way to do this:

```
val datesObs = Observable.from(dates.toIterable)
val allObs = datesObs.concatMap(reader.recordsForDate(_))
```

This has the expected performance, so all is well again.